# Downloading package punkt to /Users/macbook/nltk_data... freezes

Tags: python, nltk, freeze, textblob

I am trying to install TextBlob on Python 3.6.5. Everything is going just fine until I used this command line:
`python3 -m textblob.download_corpora`
and it started downloading package brown and package punkt. While the package brown was done and unzipped, the punkt one has been freezing for over an hour now. How can I solve this problem guys?

```
Macbooks-Air:~ macbook$ python3 -m textblob.download_corpora
[nltk_data] Downloading package brown to /Users/macbook/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora/brown.zip.
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /Users/macbook/nltk_data...
```

Comment: Similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194895/python-nltk-download-and-download-shell-both-freeze-hang-on-punkt-attempt

Comment: For the record, I agree it's possibly a duplicate, but I didn't vote to close because that question is from 2014 and only has a workaround.